# Vlookup function / merge Pandas but not exact match

Tags: python, pandas, merge, special-characters, vlookup

I have a dataframe df1:

```
Column1      Column2    Column3    Value
000_abc111   Def _ 1    xyz876     Box1
Def _ 1      11111ghi   Def _ 1    Box2
23uvw-00-11  Def _ 1    Def _ 1    Box3
```

Another df2:

```
To_Check
abc
xyza
ghi
xyz
uvw
```

To search the values of df2 in Columns 1,2 and 3 (have almost 20 columns) and return the value in the Value Column.

Result df:

```
To_Check    Value
abc         Box1
xyza    
ghi         Box2
xyz         Box1
uvw         Box3
```

The merge, map and isin functions in pandas work for the exact matches but as the data contains numbers, special characters and wide spaces in the columns so unable to figure it out (The files are csv).

Thanks.

Comment: Whats happens if multiple values match per rows? Need multiple rows in ouput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series`, then get all matched valeus by [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and last use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
s = df1.set_index('Value').stack()
df3 = s.str.extractall(f'({"|".join(df2["To_Check"])})')[0].reset_index(name='To_Check')

df = df2.merge(df3[['To_Check','Value']], how='left', on='To_Check')
print (df)
  To_Check Value
0      abc  Box1
1     xyza   NaN
2      ghi  Box2
3      xyz  Box1
4      uvw  Box3
```

If multiple values matched:

```
print (df1)

       Column1   Column2     Column3 Value
0   000_abc111   Def _ 1      xyz876  Box1
1      Def _ 1  11111ghi  Def _abc 1  Box2 <- added abc
2  23uvw-00-11   Def _ 1     Def _ 1  Box3


s = df1.set_index('Value').stack()
df3 = s.str.extractall(f'({"|".join(df2["To_Check"])})')[0].reset_index(name='To_Check')

df = df2.merge(df3[['To_Check','Value']], how='left', on='To_Check')
print (df)
  To_Check Value
0      abc  Box1
1      abc  Box2 <- 2 rows for abc
2     xyza   NaN
3      ghi  Box2
4      xyz  Box1
5      uvw  Box3
```

Or join multiple values by `groupby` with `join`:

```
s = df1.set_index('Value').stack()
df3 = (s.str.extractall(f'({"|".join(df2["To_Check"])})')[0]
       .reset_index(name='To_Check')
        .groupby('To_Check')['Value'].agg(','.join)

df = df2.join(df3, on='To_Check')
print (df)
  To_Check      Value
0      abc  Box1,Box2
1     xyza        NaN
2      ghi       Box2
3      xyz       Box1
4      uvw       Box3
```