# Compare multiple columns with special characters and merge dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have one data frame as: (df1)

```
df1_ID    Col1_df1      Col2_df1    Col3_df1
ABC-001   a.102_103i    k159*       Test1
DEF-002   a.36-89E      k188        Test2
GHI-003   ab.23<<X      e542m       Test3
```

df2:

```
df2_ID1         df2_ID2    Count    Count_A  Count_B    To_Check
                ABC-001    10       0        10         FIRSTLINE:a.102_103i:ANYTHING:EXTRA
DEF-002;GHI-003            20       2        18         SECONDLINE:ab.23<<X:ANYTHING:EXTRA
ABC-001;DEF-002            15       3        12         THIRDLINE:a.105:a.36-89D:ANYTHING:k188:EXTRA
```

RESULT (DF3):

```
df1_ID  Col1_df1    Col2_df1    Col3_df1    df2_ID1 df2_ID2 Count   Count_A Count_B To_Check
ABC-001 a.102_103i  k159*       Test1               ABC-001 10      0       10      FIRSTLINE:a.102_103i:ANYTHING:EXTRA:k159*
DEF-002 a.36-89     k188        Test2       ABC-001;DEF-002 15      3       12      THIRDLINE:a.105:a.36-89D:ANYTHING:k188:EXTRA
GHI-003 ab.23<<X    e542m       Test3       DEF-002;GHI-003 20      2       18      SECONDLINE:ab.23<<X:ANYTHING:EXTRA
```

I want to check if the values of `Col1_df1` and `Col2_df1`  are present in the `df2` column of `To_Check`. If the value exists from either `Col1_df1` and `Col2_df1` `AND` `df1_ID` is present either in the `df2_ID1` or in `df2_ID2`, then merge that row of `df2` to `df1`. If it doesn't match, then it should be BLANK.

An extension of this question:

[Vlookup function / merge Pandas but not exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69908969/vlookup-function-merge-pandas-but-not-exact-match)

But in this question, we were just dealing with strings. In my data, we have special characters also.

This syntax also doesn't seem to work when try to find the value that exists within df2:

```
df1 = df1.assign(result=df1['Col1_df1'].isin(df2['To_Check']))
```

Wrote another syntax also but not working either:

```
output = open("output.csv", "a")
with open("df1.csv", "r") as df1:
    first_line = df2.readline()
    output.write(first_line)
    with open("df2.csv", "r") as df2:
        second_first = df2.readline()
        output.write(second_first)
        for line_df1 in df1:
            df1_names = [x for x in line_df1.split(',')]
            for line_df2 in df2:
                df2_names = [x for x in line_df2.split(',')]
                check1 = any(df1_names[1] in string for string in df2_names[6])
                print(check1)
```

The `check1` is always `False` although the value exists.

Thanks for your help in advance.

*******UPDATE******

```
data_1={'df1_ID':['ABC-001','DEF-002','GHI-003']
      ,'Col1_df1':['a.102_103i','a.36-89E','ab.23<<X']
      ,'Col2_df1':['k159*','k188','e542m']
      ,'Col3_df1':['Test1','Test2','Test3']}

data_2={'df2_ID1':['','DEF-002;GHI-003','ABC-001;DEF-002']
      ,'df2_ID2':['ABC-001','','']
      ,'Count':['10','20','15']
      ,'Count_A':['0','2','3']
        ,'To_Check':['FIRSTLINE:a.102_103i:ANYTHING:EXTRA','SECONDLINE:ab.23<<X:ANYTHING:EXTRA','THIRDLINE:a.105:a.36-89D:ANYTHING:k188:EXTRA']}
```

Comment: can you provide the DataFrame constructors of the inputs?

Comment: The question is updated with the DataFrame constructors.

Comment: Are you merging based on **exact** match of string between ":" character in `To_Check`?  And why the first row in result appended `k159*` and other rows stayed as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code uses join & apply to resolve above question. Using your dataframe, new code starts after the comment line **#Data Manipulation**. Filter condition used in apply is below, you can easily change it something else required.
*((col1_df1 in To_Check) or (col2_df1 in To_Check)) AND ((df1_ID in df2_ID1) or (df1_ID in df2_ID2))*

```
import pandas as pd
data_1=pd.DataFrame({'df1_ID':['ABC-001','DEF-002','GHI-003']
      ,'Col1_df1':['a.102_103i','a.36-89E','ab.23<<X']
      ,'Col2_df1':['k159*','k188','e542m']
      ,'Col3_df1':['Test1','Test2','Test3']})

data_2=pd.DataFrame({'df2_ID1':['','DEF-002;GHI-003','ABC-001;DEF-002']
      ,'df2_ID2':['ABC-001','','']
      ,'Count':['10','20','15']
      ,'Count_A':['0','2','3']
        ,'To_Check':['FIRSTLINE:a.102_103i:ANYTHING:EXTRA','SECONDLINE:ab.23<<X:ANYTHING:EXTRA','THIRDLINE:a.105:a.36-89D:ANYTHING:k188:EXTRA']})

# Data Manuplation 
data_1['join_col'] = 1
data_2['join_col'] = 1

df = pd.merge(data_1, data_2, left_on='join_col', right_on='join_col')

df['Is_Match'] = df[['df1_ID','Col1_df1','Col2_df1','df2_ID1','df2_ID2','To_Check']].\
apply(lambda x: (((x[5].find(x[1].strip()))>-1)|((x[5].find(x[2].strip()))>-1)) and  ((x[3].find(x[0].strip())>-1)|(x[4].find(x[0].strip())>-1)) , axis=1)

df[df['Is_Match']==True].drop(['join_col','Is_Match'], axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Need a little clarification on what condition means that a row should be merged from df2 into df1, as well as what that merge should look like.

This code segment does what I think you're looking for in terms of the conditional, but I just added a col to df1 that tracks which col from df1 matched some rows To_Check in df2, as well as the ID of that row from df2

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)


check = []
for df1_ind in df1.index:
    found = ""
    for df2_ind in df2.index:
        col1_check = df1["Col1_df1"][df1_ind] in df2["To_Check"][df2_ind]
        col2_check = df1["Col2_df1"][df1_ind] in df2["To_Check"][df2_ind]
        df1_id_present = df1["df1_ID"][df1_ind] in [df2['df2_ID1'][df2_ind], df2['df2_ID2'][df2_ind]]
        # wasn't sure if that first conditional meant the df1_id being present effected the column checks
        if col1_check:
            found += f"Col_1_present(df2_ID={df2_ind})::"
        if col2_check:
            found += f"Col_2_present(df2_ID={df2_ind})::"
        if not found == "":
            # this means the cols from df1 we are looking for in df2 were found at some row. 
            # leave the inner for loop and save these results
            # unless you expect the row contents to appear in multiple rows of df2
            break 
    if found == "":
        found = "false"
    check.append(found)

df1['Checks'] = check
print(df1.head())
```

output:

```
    df1_ID    Col1_df1 Col2_df1 Col3_df1                      Checks
0  ABC-001  a.102_103i    k159*    Test1  Col_1_present:(df2_ID=0)::
1  DEF-002    a.36-89E     k188    Test2              Col_2_present:
2  GHI-003    ab.23<<X    e542m    Test3              Col_1_present:
```