# Pandas compare Dataframes to search not exact match

Tags: pandas, dataframe, string-comparison

I got two data frames df1 and df1 but there is not like ID match column to merge, im trying to find a way to compare df1.Code with df2.Code, if df1.Code contains some of the values in df2.Code, like grep works in bash, for example if i grep for 701622  i will get all Codes that contain 701622  :

```
cat df1.csv | grep 701622

2017016220 
    
2017016221 

2017016222  

2159701622

2088701622
```

Could contain the values  at the beginning, middle or end

Code       object
Alias    object

**df1:**

```
       | Code       |   Alias
        ----------------------  
0      | 2017016220 |    B  
1      | 2017016221 |    B   
2      | 2017016222 |    B
```

**df2:**

```
Code       object
Id         object


      |  To_check     |   Id

0     |  112948       |      1045

1     |  115424       |      1045
 
2     |  110825       |      1277

3     |  109647       |      1277

4     |  109321       |      1277

5     |  701622       |      6565
```

Note: both files are quite big 50M lines

I think i can't use merge as there is no  similar column on both dataframes, but not sure if pandas has already a function for this?

I saw what works similar is function contains():

note: Initial the object code types was int64

```py
df3=df1[df1['Code'].astype('str').str.contains('701622')]
```

But as per documentation it only works if i pass a string not a list

i was trying to follow the post:
[Vlookup function / merge Pandas but not exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69908969/vlookup-function-merge-pandas-but-not-exact-match)

But i get lost on the Join as it says empty

```
s = dfcsv.set_index('Code').stack()

df3 = s.str.extractall(f'({"|".join(df2["To_Check"])})')[0].reset_index(name='To_Check')

print(df)

Columns: [Code, level_1, match, To_Check]
Index: []
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is very hard to read. Please format it and provide clear table structure as explained in [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables).

Comment: Hello Tahnk you for your help that post help to  make de join and filter: